# Getting ImportError: No module named document for any cloudant import

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, cloudant, python-cloudant

I'm trying to use cloudant-python library in my application, but I'm not able to import the library itself as I'm getting `ImportError: No module named document` as soon as I try to import anything from cloudant context. Following are details:

- Cloudant version: *cloudant-2.6.1.dev0*
- Python version:  *Python 2.7.9*
- Example codes which are giving error:

`from cloudant.document import Document`

OR

`from cloudant.client import Cloudant`

OR

`from cloudant import Cloudant`

The **error** is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "cloudant.py", line 1, in <module>
  from cloudant.document import Document
ImportError: No module named document
```

Comment: Can you check if Cloudant module is properly installed?. Try using ">>> help("modules")" in python interpreter.

Comment: If I run `from cloudant.client import Cloudant` on python interpreter, it's working as expected but if I include in script anywhere, then it returns error.

Comment: are you using virtual environment and somehow it is not activated when you are running the script?

Comment: Same is happening with `cloudant.account`,`cloudant.document`,`cloudant.client` and so on..

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved as I corrected very silly mistake, I named my script file as `cloudant.py` so instead of looking for `cloudant.__something__` in library package it was searching the same script file, duh!